# sbt share dependencies across projects

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I'm looking for a way to share configuration (dependencies for example) across projects (but not subprojects).

I was wondering if it was possible to centralize dependencies in some sbt project and get those from several other sbt projects.

If there is no simple way, should I consider developping a plugin to expose those dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe developing a plugin containing this settings is the best solution here.
This plugin would then be an independend project, and it can be reused across projects by using addSbtPlugin(...).
You could use a local repository to host the (built) plugin.

Comment: An sbt plugin doesn't cut it because you need to manage the version of the plugin in every sbt build whenever you change or update the shared versions. I bet you'll forget to do so. This is equivalent to updating the versions by hand and not sharing them.

Comment: If the shared configuration options change often, a plugin is a bad solution. But for rather static settings (task definitions, common dependency sets) it may be a good solution.
Also you can version your plugin - and thus provide different snapshots of your shared settings.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to publish all common dependencies to a Maven repo.

However, I prefer multi-module project mechanism. Below is an example (Play):

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "1.0",
  organization := "abc",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.6",
  resolvers ++= Seq(
    ...
  ),
  ...
)
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .aggregate(core, dao, models)
  .settings(
    name := "root",
    version := "1.0",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    ...
  )
)
lazy val core = (project in file("./modules/core")) dependsOn dao     settings(commonSettings: _*) settings(
  name := "core",
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...
 )
) 
lazy val dao = (project in file("./modules/dao")) dependsOn models   settings(commonSettings: _*) settings(
  name := "dao",
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...
 )
)
lazy val models = (project in file("./modules/models")) settings(commonSettings: _*) settings(
  name:= "models",
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...
 )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I do also like multi module project but there are project that are too big for that.